# Поиск по БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel5

Всем привет. Стоит задача разработать интернет магазин по продаже pdf файлов. 
При добавлении товара, автоматически генерируется 6 поисковых тегов, по которым будет вестись поиск. Пользователь будет вводить строку запроса (типо как в гугл), и ему будет выводится результат поиска. Я сделал две таблице в бд : 
 1. Таблица с  информацией о товаре
 2. Таблица поисковых тегов, в которой поля product_id и tag 
Пользователь вводит запрос, я ищу совпадения в таблице тегов, вытаскиваю оттуда prodcut_id, а затем по product_id вытаскиваю записи с таблице товаров. Но мне кажется, что когда в таблице товаров будет 100 тысяч записей, а в таблице тегов 600 тысяч, то бд будет сильно тормозить, и поиск будет очень долго длится. 
Проект делаю на Laravel. Подскажите как лучше сделать .

Comment: *мне кажется, что когда в таблице товаров будет 100 тысяч записей, а в таблице тегов 600 тысяч, то бд будет сильно тормозить* 600к записей - это в общем несерьёзно. Особенно с учётом интерактивности. Правильно построенные индексы - всё, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Способ 1. Если теги не обязательно брать из списка, то можно обойтись без второй таблицы и хранить прямо в таблице с информацией о товаре и разделять `.` или `;` и делать поиск по тегам через `like`.

Способ 2. Индексы. Просто создай индексы. Они как раз нужны, чтобы ускорять такие запросы. Ну и вот [статья](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/MySQL_indexes.html) по этому поводу

UPD: Но первый способ не надо использовать (см. комменты)

Comment: Совет денормализовать данные - безусловно вредный.

Comment: Ну тогда индексы чем плохи?

Comment: Против индексов я как раз ничего не имею.